# In Python, where does the Break command go in a infinite While Loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I stole this code from an answer given 2 years ago by someone else with regard to error handling, where the program is looking for an int but getting a non-int value.

My IDE (PyCharm 2021.3.3) on 64 Bit  Windows 7 is telling me that the "break" statement is outside of the loop. Is the answer incorrect, or am I missing something?

The original code in the answer was:

```
while True: #loop forever
    try:
        u = int(input("Please, enter a number: ")) #this tries to accept your input and convert it to integer
    except ValueError:                   #executes if there is an error in try
        print("That isn't a valid integer, please try again")
    else:
        print("u =",u)
        break  #break the loop if there was no mistakes in try clause
```

The error I am getting is:

break  #break the loop if there was no mistakes in try clause
^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Comment: What IDE (and what version of Python, on what OS) are you using? Looking at this in PyCharm on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, using Python 3.9, there's no warnings and no errors and the code works as expected. Also, is the code embedded in some more code? It may be that this fragment doesn't have an inherent issue, but the surrounding code may change that. Another likely cause is indentation - if the indentation of the `else` is incorrect in your program, it may be considered part of the `while` instead of the `try .. except`

Comment: I am using PyCharm as well, and Python 3.7., Windows 7. BTW, how did you format that code. When I blocked the section of code, it created that continuous line.

Comment: The error I am getting is:break  #break the loop if there was no mistakes in try clause
    ^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Comment: (the inline code formatting is created by adding single backticks around the `code`) Please update your question, don't add information in the comments.

Comment: Again, look at your code.  If the `else:` in your code is lined up with the `while`, that would be a syntax error, because the `else:` only occurs when the loop exits.  If the `else:` is lined up with the `try:` and `except:`, then it should be right.

Comment: Thank you Tim. It does appear to be an issue where the `else:` was indeed misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

With this formatting it works for me.
Python 3.10.4 - Windows 10, Windows Terminal(PowerShell), IDE: Notepad++